# After upgrade admin menu not coming

Tags: 7, upgrading

After upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 successfully, the admin menu links are disappeared.

[image]

I have carefully followed the steps to upgrade it successfully. But after upgrade, I changed the administration theme to Seven and everything was working but the administration menu. What could be the problem?

Update: Management Menu snapshot

[image]

I tried to see if the problem is with Menu, so I installed [Admin menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) but after that admin menu appearing. Only problem is with Drupal7 default toolbar. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: Check what's in your "Management" menu at: /admin/structure/menu/manage/management This should be what the Admin menu uses. (+ "Navigation" menu for "Add Content" links)

Comment: Thanks. I also suspected the same and found Management menu looks fine.. Of course I have to reorder it after upgrade. But still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell you why, but can tell you how I fixed it last time when it happened to me:

1. Disable Admin Menu
2. Uninstall it if possible
3. Delete it's files and directory
4. Download and unpack fresh copy
5. Clear all caches (Drupal and browser)
6. Enable Admin menu

Worked for me, when menu disappeared during 6.x -> 6.x upgrade, when everything else failed to bring it back.

If the problem is only with core toolbar module, and not [Admin Menu module](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu), you have 2 options, really:

1. Try steps above, just for Toolbar. You can download core archive and then just extract toolbar's directory. Admin menu and toolbar are build in similar fashion, and purging all module's data is a pretty solid method anyway, so it still can work.
2. Give up on toolbar, and use 3rd party module instead.

Comment: Turning off the client-side caching option often helps too

Comment: @Clive well, back then it didn't, and when we repeated the process (it was on dev machine) it wasn't needed if steps above was applied, and that's why it is not in my answer. But good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Mołot During minor upgrade, it works fine. But after upgrading to D7 only admin menu not appearing

Comment: @pown did you try the steps above, and commenting they don't work? Or you didn't even try, because you think it cannot work?

Comment: @Mołot: there is no admin menu used in drupal6, in drupal 7 administration menu comes in core(toolbar module) which is coming but not listing menu's, thats the problem.

Comment: @pown you used a name of a very, very popular module, when you didn't meant that module. Simple collision of concepts. So, what happens if you turn off toolbar, and install [Administration Menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module instead?

Comment: @Mołot: I dont want to install administration menu module, I just wanted the core admin-menu listing when toolbar module is enabled. i tried disabling and enabling toolbar module number of times, but no luck

Comment: @pown OK, so tell us if this is a problem with menu itself, or with toolbar module? You can do it by displaying administration menu using any other module than toolbar... I suggested you one, but if you don't want it, well, test with any other, whatever you prefer.